# Source files vs binary files: what's the purpose of providing both?

Tags: .net, binary

here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

offers both source and binary files. If I am a programmer who needs to use the files, why should they be providing me with both? Why not just give me the source and I will compile it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people don't have the compiler, but want to run the software.

Comment: Thanks for making the opposite viewpoint look dumb. (Because it is!)

Answer (score 2):

In case the user wants to see the application run before digging into the source.

Answer (score 1):

It is convention on CodeProject to provide a working solution and source code as separate packages. Users of the site come to expect it.